# JavaScript Object Inheritance - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, object

What is wrong with this code? Can somebody help me with JavaScript Object Inheritance? I am starting to feel like an idiot!!

Thanks in advance,
Sam

```
function Human(name, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
};

function Man(name) {
    Man.prototype = new Human(name, "Male");
};

var m = new Man("Sam Striano");
alert(m.name); //<-- = Undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually two steps to mimic classical inheritance in javascript:

1. Your subclass constructor needs to call the parent constructor
2. Your subclass prototype needs to chain into the parent prototype

the first step usually looks like

```
function Subclass(blah) {
    ParentClass.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

The second step is trickier. On JS environments that implement the `__proto__` property, you could do

```
Subclass.prototype = {
    __proto__ : ParentClass.prototype,
    subclassMethod1: function() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Unless you know exactly where your script will run (like in a node.js environment), you can't rely on `__proto__` being available to your script, so the general approach will require to use [Crockford's object() method](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html):

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
Subclass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
Subclass.prototype.subclassMethod1 = function() { /* ... */ }
```

That's the gist of it. ES5 runtimes may have `Object.create()` already built-in, and that's fine.

There are leftover things to complete the illusion of classic inheritance, such as the ability to easily call a parent class' overriden method. With what we have now, you'd need to have something like `ParentClass.prototype.overridenMethod.call(this, arg1, arg2)` in your Subclass method.
Some OO libraries will helpfully define extra cruft on each of your subclass instances so you can use things like `this.superclass.overridenMethod(arg1, arg2)`.

The implementation of that cruft is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: Do the methods have to be defined in the base as well as the sub? Could you show me a complete example of basic classical inheritance using JavaScript [please]?

Answer (score 2):

You want this instead:

```
function Man(name) {
    Human.call(this, name, "Male");
}
```

**What that code does**

It seems like you're only trying to call the constructor of the parent, `Human`, which isn't the same is prototypal inheritance. The code above takes the constructor for `Human` and applies it to `this` - a new `Man` object.

**What your code does**

The line `Man.prototype = new Human(name, "Male")` is changing the prototype of `Man` ***every time a new Man is created***. Not only that, you're completing re-assigning the prototype object, and so it will only apply to objects created ***after*** that assignment - i.e. not the first one. Hence, `m.name` is undefined.

**Proper prototypal inheritance**

Note that calling the parent's constructor, as in my code above, *won't* cause `Man` to automatically inherit any methods assigned to `Human.prototype`. The best way to do this is to clone `Human.prototype` into `Man.prototype` but outside of any constructors. Like this:

```
function Man(name) {
    Human.call(this, name, "Male");
}

function inherit(parent, child) {
    if (Object.create) child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    else {
        for (var key in parent.prototype) {
            if (!parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            child.prototype[key] = parent.prototype[key];
        }
    }
}

inherit(Human, Man);
```

This may seem rather verbose, and the alternative may be to do this:

```
Man.prototype = new Human('no name', 'Male');
```

Which *will work*, but causes unwanted side-effects since we're forced to assign a dud name to the `prototype`, and it's letting the constructor for `Human` call an extra time just for assigning the prototype. Be warned if you go down this path and later change the `Human` constructor to do more than just assign properties to `this`.

Comment: What is the difference between prototype and "__prototype__"?

Comment: Like String, Array, Number, Boolean, etc? So this example you give is not "Prototypical Inheritance"?

Comment: @Sam, My mistake, I think you mean `__proto__`. It is to tie a new object to the prototype of the function that constructed it. It shouldn't be used though, see this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @Sam, please see my updated answer on how to inherit properly.

Comment: @Sam, patrick's answer is using the second method I described, which is a valid answer, but I described the problems associated with it which is why I'd avoid it. Is there a specific part which isn't clear?

Comment: @Sam, yes, metal's last code example is doing the same thing, but in a rather clever way :) The thing to keep in mind is that inheritance is not so straightforward in JS -- it's rather manual, and the best practice is to keep the constructors separate from the prototypes.

Comment: Instead of `Man.prototype = new Human('no name', 'Male')` you can use a surrogate constructor so you don't have to call the base constructor just to setup inheritance. `var ctor = function() {}; ctor.prototype = Human.prototype; Man.prototype = new ctor(); Man.prototype.constructor = Man;`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is to have the `Man` class in inherit properties from `Human`. You're on the right track, but would need to apply a new `Human` instance once as the prototype object of `Man`.

```
function Human(name, sex) {
    this.name = "some default";
    this.sex = sex;
};

function Man(name) {
    if( name !== undefined )
        this.name = name;
};
Man.prototype = new Human(name, "Male");
Man.prototype.constructor = Man;

var m = new Man("Sam Striano");

alert(m.name);  // alerts "Sam Striano"
alert(m.sex);   // alerts "Male"
```

Comment: @Sam: Which part are you confused about?

Comment: @Sam: [Here's an example of how I might implement it](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyg3s/). There are a couple items prototyped onto `Human`, which will apply to all `Humans`. Then each `Human` instance can have a property of `sex` that will be used in its role as a parent class to `Man` and `Woman`. Then each `Man` can have its own `name` property. Because `Human` has a `speak` function that alerts `name`, each `Man` can speak its own `name`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you should handle all stuff with `prototype` and `constructor` and the inerithance could be managed in this way:

```
// Define superclass      
function Human( name, sex ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
}                                 

// Define superclass methods      
Human.prototype.method1 = function() {
   alert( 'This is the call to ORIGINAL method1() with name: ' + this.name + ' and sex: ' + this.sex );
}

// Define subclass      
function Man( name, age ) {                                        
    this.constructor.apply( this, [ name, 'Man' ] );
    this.age = age;
}      

// Define subclass inerithance
Man.prototype = new Human();

// Define subclass methods
Man.prototype.method1 = function() {
    alert( 'This is the call to OVERWRITE method1() with name: ' + this.name + ' and sex: ' + this.sex + ' and age: ' + this.age );
    this.constructor.prototype.method1.apply( this );
}

var m = new Man( 'Sam Satriano', 30 );
m.method1();
// Should alert:
// This is the call to OVERWRITE method1() with name: Sam Satriano and sex: Man and age: 30
// This is the call to ORIGINAL method1() with name: Sam Satriano and sex: Man
```

Hope this helps. Ciao!

Comment: Btw, there's a couple of interesting jQuery plugins (like low-pro https://github.com/danwrong/low-pro-for-jquery/) that also simulate the "super" behaviour.

Comment: In your Man constructor, you want to call the parent's constructor, not the same constructor. Your example only works because you did not fix the constructor property on the prototype after `Man.prototype = new Human()` as you should when setting up inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into an inheritance fight, your problem can be solved by changing your code to the following:

```
function Human(name, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
};

function Man(name) {
    // This is how you call the parent's constructor
    Human.call(this, name, "Male");
};

// The call to setup the prototype only needs to happen once
// Not in every instantiation of the object
Man.prototype = new Human();
// Have to fix the constructor, right now it's set to Human
Man.prototype.constructor = Man;

var m = new Man("Sam Striano");
>> m.name // outputs "Sam Striano";
>> m instanceof Human // outputs true
```

This is still not an ideal way to inherit. I posted something explaining what makes good JS inheritance.  http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html